# Adding environment variables to already deployed application in OpenShift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I currently have a process in place to build and deploy our application to OpenShift utilizing the Jenkins OpenShift plugin via the commands below:

```
openshift.newBuild("--image-stream=${builderImageName}", "--binary=true", "-n ${projectName}", "--to=${applicationName}:${targetEnv}")
openshift.startBuild("${applicationName}", "--from-dir=.", "--wait=true", "-n ${projectName}")
openshift.newApp("-n ${projectName}", "--template=${templateName}", "--param-file=${appDeployConfigFileName}", "--env-file=${appEnvFileName}")
```

This works as intended. My question is once the app has been deployed how can I update the env variables if additional ones need to be added? I basically want to duplicate the functionality of going through the ui and adding env variables. However I would want to do this using the openshift plugin or oc tool and use a file of variables not just a set of key values.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the deployment config for your application

```
oc set env dc/<your_app> MYVAR=foo -n <project_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this and it works but the problem with this solution is that there may be multiple env variables to be added. Initially they are passed in a env-file in new app. If I wanted to store this file in SCM and then update the variables I would have to do some parsing and string together the command. I was hoping for a way to pass the entire file in again.

Comment: Consider using a config map then instead. This would hold the original key/values. Then when adding environment variables to the deployment config, reference them from the config map. You can then edit/replace the config map in one go and the re-deployment will automatically trigger.

Comment: Correct answer is to use a ConfigMap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have limited experience with the config map but found that the DeploymentConfig template needs to be updated for each environment variable that would be added to the configmap. Since the template is utilized in the newApp command to deploy the original application how would the DeploymentConfig then be updated? Or is there a way to utilize the config map without a direct reference to each variable in the DeploymentConfig?

Comment: You can edit the deployment  config after you create the application - `oc edit dc <your_app>` or  `oc patch dc/<yourapp> --patch '{your_change}'`

Comment: That seems like it would be tedious to script in Jenkins as well for each env variable if there were multiple. Ideally, oc set env would take a file input and overwrite all env variables set in the dc. Maybe there just isnt a way to do this as simply as I would hope. Thanks for the input everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to store environment variables in SCM with a builder image (w/ S2I aka source-to-image enabled container image), use an environment file `.s2i/environment`.

- Docs:
  https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#environment-files
- Example:
  https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel-ex/blob/master/.s2i/environment

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I dont want to couple the environment variables to the build as they will change from environment to environment. I want to specify them in the DeploymentConfig.